# Extra text... after read more tag

Tags: read-more

I have some `<!--more-->` tags in my posts and they work...to a degree. 
Instead of doing a hard break after the `<!--more-->` tag, it continues on to show some of the next paragraph of text followed by a `...`

How can I get the `<!--more-->` tag to be a hard break?

Thanks

[example on homepage](http://santacruzsurvivors.com)

Comment: You need to show use how your theme is handling this code-wise.

Comment: I'm still a wordpress noob, I need to know which code specifically you need to see. Some keywords I can search for?

Comment: review http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: this seems to be the meat & potatos of the function but I dont know what to modify. maybe you can suggest? `$maxchar=(strpos($content, '<!--more-->'))?strpos(preg_replace('/<.*?>/', '', preg_replace('/<!--more-->/','@smt_readmore_tag',$content)), '@smt_readmore_tag'):$maxchar;`

Answer (score 2):

The more-Tag have a filter, you can enhance this with a small plugin like the follow example.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: br after more-Tag
 * Description: Add content of var $extra_more after more-Tag
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */

! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) and exit;

add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'custom_more_link', 9999 );
function custom_more_link( $more_link ) {

    $extra_more = '<br>'; // here add your break

    return $more_link . $extra_more;
}
```

If you will replace the more tag with your markup, then use a small plugin and `preg_replace`.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'fb_more_link' );
function fb_more_link( $content ) {

    // only on single posts
    if ( ! is_single() )
        return $content;

    // adsense code
    $my_content = '<br>';

    // replace more tag
    $content = preg_replace('/<span id\=\"(more\-\d+)"><\/span>/', $my_content, $content);
    return $content;
}
```